# Do methods executed within a EF DbContext Transaction inherit it?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext

When using EF and wrapping a conditional block in a transaction, as long as the DbContext is passed into a method inside the block, will it inherit the transaction that was started?

Example, the DbContext is passed into the method as the last parameter:

```
var db = new DbContext();
if(action == "Remove")
{
    using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction()
    {
        try 
        {
            MyMethod(param1, param2, db);
            //do some more things to another db table
            db.SaveChanges();
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The method also contains a SaveChanges():

```
public static void MyMethod(int param1, string param2, DbContext db)
{
    try
    {
        //do some table updates 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        //throw exception
    }
}
```

So, I assume that if the method fails for whatever reason then the entire transaction gets rolled back? And, if the method is successful but the changes made outside the method (but still inside the transaction) fail, then the changes made by the method are also rolled back?

This particular set of circumstances is not documented within the EF guides, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You could of course just try what happens when you comment out `tran.Commit();`. BTW, you should remove the exception handling: it swallows all exceptions and a transaction, when it goes out of scope, is always rolled-back anyway if it's not explicitly committed.

Comment: Yes, and with a scoped transaction this should be the only time you consider calling `SaveChanges` more than once on a `DbContext`. Note that in your example the `DbContext` should be scoped in a `using` block or managed as an injected dependency. It is a Disposable class and should be alive only as long as necessary since it will be potentially tracking references to entities it loads or otherwise interacts with.

Answer (score 0):

you are right. When you pass the Context to the method you have the transaction

```
if(action == "Remove")
{
    using (var db = new DB_Context())
    {
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction()
        {
            try 
            {
                MyMethod(param1, param2, db);
                //do some more things to another db table
                db.SaveChanges();
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                tran.Rollback();  //It is not required. Using(...) {...} will automatically call Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

public static void MyMethod(int param1, string param2, DbContext db)
{
    try
    {
        //do some table updates 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```